# Same node in dead and in live nodes list at Hadoop 2.2

Tags: hadoop, upgrade, hdfs

It seems that the same nodes appear in dead nodes list and in live nodes list as well at HDFS web page.
How to get rid of these "dead" nodes?

I have just upgraded the Apache Hadoop on our cluster of 480 nodes from version 1.2.1 to 2.2.0.
Everything worked well. The number of blocks, the files are the same in the old and the new version. FSCK report no problems.

I have 480 live nodes. What is odd is that I have 23 dead nodes shown on the hdfs admin page. 
Somehow these 23 dead nodes can be found in the live nodes list as well. They have the same name and ip in both lists (live and dead).

As result of `hadoop dfs admin -report` I get:

```
Datanodes available: 480 (503 total, 23 dead)
```

This is the statistic of a dead node in a report:

```
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
Non DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: 100.00%
DFS Remaining%: 0.00%
Last contact: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
```

I have checked and only one instance of the DataNode software is running on these 23 nodes.
If I stop one datanode from the live list that exists in the dead list as well, then after 10 minutes the node appears twice in the dead list.
If I start the datanode again, the node appears in the live list but one instance still exists in the dead list.
I have checked the namenode logs but didn't find any errors. I have also restarted Hadoop many times. Each time these same 23 nodes appear in the dead list.

I see now that the problem is a network topology. I have used

> ./hdfs dfsadmin -printTopology

command, and realized that the 23 dead nodes are associated with /default-rack and /rack6 as well. I have 12 racks for the 480 nodes.

But still my network topology resolver works well, so I cannot understand why does the nodes are associated with default rack as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6180
view your conf of "dfs.hosts" in hdfs-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. 
We have upgraded the cluster to Apache Hadoop 2.5 and the false dead nodes have disappeared.